ActiveMQ Artemis missing MBeans
The MBeans for ConsumerCount on each queue, TotalConsumerCount and ConnectionCount are exposed but why not ProducerCount and SessionCount?
Why do I need it?
I have set alerts for the number of consumers and the number of connection, but don't have for number of Producers and Sessions. The increasing number of producer and session from one connection can easily consume resources like CPU and Memory both, creating OOM or eventually a crash.
Also, Can I limit the number of producers and consumers of a given session?

Why limiting number of connections doesn't work for me?
I got a scenario where one connection created more than some thousands of sessions under one connection which led to a crash.
